# Add to list elements Async in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, handler

I'm rather new to JAVA and have a problem similar to the one mentioned below, where I want to add elements to an array via async processing.
However, the returned array is with size 0 and not the correct size.

```
// Iterate over the products and transform them asynchronously
List<String> transformed = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product product : products) {
    product.transform(rh -> {
        transformed.add(rh.result());
    });
}
// Check the transformed list.
System.out.println(transformed.size()) // should be 10 but is 0
```

I could not find a simple tested solution for this. What would be an example implementation for this in JAVA?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. If `transformed` is really **empty** after the loop, then the only explanation is: `product.transform()` either doesn't invoke the lambda passed to it, or it does it with significant delay (on another thread). How to "best" approach this really depends on your exact requirements, the frameworks you are using, etc. pp.

Comment: And as the now deleted answer suggested, **one** way could be to look into CompletableFuture, CompletionStage and Future and such things. But as said, it really depends on context.

Comment: If your list is being modified by another thread, I guess you may want it to be a [synchronized list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-). Also, as stated above, assuming that `Product::transform` does the job asynchronously, it is highly possible that your main thread reaches `System.out.println` before the other thread(s) had the time to actually fill the list with `rh.result()`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to extends Thread in Product, then implement the function run() with an @Override. That's make you able to do your loop like this :

```
// Iterate over the products and transform them asynchronously
List<String> transformed = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product product : products) {
    transformed.add(product.start());
}
// Check the transformed list.
System.out.println(transformed.size()) // should be 10 but is 0
```

The .start() start a new Thread who run the méthode run().

You can also give your ArrayList transformed as an attribut for Product then in product .add() in transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question, but one possible way to do it would be using a parallel stream and either using mapping or foreach on top of your products list.

I made some assumptions, just to create an example, but here's how it looks

```
    private void yourMethod(List products){
    List<String> transformed = products.parallelStream().map(this::transformation).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Check the transformed list.
    System.out.println(transformed.size());
}

private String transformation(Product product){
    // do some transformation
    return "some transformed";
}
```